# Background image not displaying Outlook 2016 desktop

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

The background image looks fine when I view my page locally but when I try to add it as plain text within the Outlook 2016 desktop application the background image is gone. Anny help appreciated.

```
<table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;" role="presentation">
    <tr>
        <td class="padding content" style="padding-top: 90px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px; width: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/9cTRh0Y/confetti.png);">
            <p style="font-size: 23px; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 5px; line-height: 28px;">
                Announcing the Self-Service Password Reset <br />
                <strong style="color: #007da5;">Raffle Winner</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px;">
                Thank you to everyone who registered for the SSPR feature. <br />
                Out of everyone in ICT we had 48 people register! <br />
                Without further ado, the winner of the <strong>$20 gift card to Starbucks</strong> is...
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 23px; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 5px; line-height: 28px;">Winner!</p>
            <p style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 23px;">The winner will be contacted separately to receive their prize</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is that it looks like locally
[image]
And this is what I get when I loaded into Outlook 2016
[image]

Comment: Perhaps Outlook isn't downloading external resources outside of your domain for security purposes?

Comment: @PatrickGregorio I was thinking that but I have a few images above (not seen in photo) that are external and they render just fine. The issue seems isolated to background images

Comment: Seems like background images on table cells aren't supported: https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6068-background-image-on-windows-outlook-not-displaying

Comment: The answer here looks to be a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264126/css-background-image-image-not-showing-up-in-outlook

Comment: @PatrickGregorio you are correct. I have discovered that it is supported for Outlook 2016 and up on windows 10 if VML is included.